# Run `pigpiod` daemon over remote Linux

Tags: python

`pigpiod` is a daemon to control Remote GPIO (Raspberry Pi).
I'm trying to load it remotely from rpi#1 on rpi#2, unsuccessfuly.

Both RPi run Python 3.5 With Ubuntu 16.04.

when using on local machine- daemon's executed OK:

```
def runpigpiod_local():
    subprocess.run(['sudo','pigpiod'])
```

BUT- when trying to execute it remotely- it fails

```
def runpigpiod(adress):
    result = subprocess.run(['ssh','guy@192.168.2.112','sudo pigpiod'])
```

output:

```
guy@192.168.2.112's password: 
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question is answered in:
[Configuring Remote GPIO](http://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/remote_gpio.html)